# Pass equation as argument into function

Tags: r

I was told that passing equation as strings and evaluating them is bad practice. How can I still create a function which takes an equation and evaluates it without the string version and without using third party packages?

This is my function:

```
replaceFormula <- function(df, column, formula){
  df[column] <- eval(parse(text=formula), df)
  return(df)
}
```

This is my use case:

```
set.seed(24)
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
replaceFormula(df, 'V5', 'V3+V4')
```

**Update:**

Is this also possible with conditions?
My example function:

```
replaceFactor <- function(df, column, condition, what){
  df[column] <- sapply(df[column],function(x) ifelse(eval(parse(text=condition), df), what, x))
  return(df)
}
```

My usecase:

```
set.seed(24)
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
replaceFactor(df, 'V5', 'V1==1', 'GOOD')
```

Comment: Look at the help page '?reformulate'.

Comment: Based on your new condition, I updated my post.  Please check if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've crafted yourself a kludgey version of `transform`

```
> set.seed(24)
> dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
> df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
> transform(df, V5 = V3 + V4)
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  5  3  5  8
2  1  1  2  1  3
3  4  4  4 NA NA
4  3  4  4  3  7
5  3  1  1 NA NA
```

Comment: Quick second question: Is there a similar way to pass a condition as a argument too? For example I have this function: `replaceFactor <- function(df, column, condition, what){
  df[column] <- sapply(df[column],function(x) ifelse(eval(parse(text=condition), df), what, x))
  return(df)
}`

Comment: @Blind0ne I don't really understand what you're trying to do with that code

Comment: Other option similar to your answer is `within(df, V5 <- V3+V4)`

Comment: @Dason usecase with the same dataframe: `replaceFactor(df, 'V5', 'V1==1', 'GOOD')` It should just replace the values if the a condition is met in another column

Comment: @akrun Nice. I prefer the `transform` version but I haven't thought about `within` in a long time so it's a nice reminder.

Answer (score 1):

We can pass the formula as a `quosure` and evaluate it by unquoting (`!!` or `UQ`) in the devel version of `dplyr` (or soon to be released `0.6.0`)

```
library(dplyr)
replaceFormula <- function(dat, Col, form){
      Col <- quo_name(enquo(Col))
      dat %>% 
          mutate(UQ(Col) := UQ(form))
  }


replaceFormula(df, V5, quo(V3 + V4)) 
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  5  3  5  8
#2  1  1  2  1  3
#3  4  4  4 NA NA
#4  3  4  4  3  7
#5  3  1  1 NA NA
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, we can also pass an expression to evaluate and change the values based on that

```
replaceFormulaNew <- function(dat, Col, form, what){
      Col <- enquo(Col)
      ColN <- quo_name(Col)
      what <- quo_name(enquo(what))


      dat %>% 
          mutate(UQ(ColN) := ifelse(UQ(form), what, UQ(Col)))
  }


replaceFormulaNew(df, V5, quo(V1==1), GOOD)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4   V5
#1  1  5  3  5 GOOD
#2  1  1  2  1 GOOD
#3  4  4  4 NA    4
#4  3  4  4  3 <NA>
#5  3  1  1 NA    1

replaceFormulaNew(df, V5, quo(V3 < V4), GOOD)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4   V5
#1  1  5  3  5 GOOD
#2  1  1  2  1    3
#3  4  4  4 NA <NA>
#4  3  4  4  3 <NA>
#5  3  1  1 NA <NA>
```

The `enquo` takes the input argument and convert it to `quosure` while `quo_name` converts it to string for evaluation in `mutate` to assign the evaluated output to the column specified in the input

Comment: just fyi, they specifically asked for a solution without third party packages

Comment: @docendodiscimus  I agree that the OP may not want a third party package, but I think others who read the post would benefit from it.  Also, the OP seems to want a formula to pass into a function.

Comment: that's completely independent of your answer and the point I was making. Anyway, I don't mind your answer

Comment: @akrun - What do you mean by "not passing arguments into a function". I'm pretty sure it's passing the input data and an expression in as arguments. Just because it's not string inputs and it's not a function I defined... I just don't see what your argument is there. Not trying to be confrontational... it just seems like an odd statement.

Comment: @Dason I am referring to the way OP defined a function and what I understand was that he wanted to pass it as  a string to be evaluated.

Comment: thanks @akrun you're a beast i know you love the dplyr package :) is there also a way without using other packages?

Comment: @BlindOne Thank you for the compliments.  I am still learning a lot thanks to your guys asking some probing questions.  In base R, you may be able to do it without eval(parse and stuff like that, but it is already in your post, right